# Arraylist not working properly

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have this code in Android Studio:

```
           for (ArrayList<Bitmap> arr : imgs) {
                for (Bitmap img : arr) {
                    if (img != null) {
                        arrayList.add(img.getHeight());
                    }
                    else {
                        arrayList.add(null);
                    }
                }
                heights.add(arrayList);
                arrayList.clear();
            }
```

With imgs declared and filled earlier and heights declared as an

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>
```

What I get is:

```
[[58]]
[[null], [null]]
[[75], [75], [75]]
[[null], [null], [null], [null]]
[[1200], [1200], [1200], [1200], [1200]]
[[960], [960], [960], [960], [960], [960]]
[[960], [960], [960], [960], [960], [960], [960]]
[[612], [612], [612], [612], [612], [612], [612], [612]]
[[1632], [1632], [1632], [1632], [1632], [1632], [1632], [1632]]
```

And so on. Every time it doesn't add the value to the array but it replaces all the values in it with the new one. What's wrong?

Comment: `ArrayList` is working fine. Start by assuming it's your code that's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
heights.add(arrayList);
arrayList.clear();
```

You always add the same `arrayList` instance to `heights`, and you clear it, so all the previous values are lost.

You should create a new `ArrayList` instance in each iteration of the outer loop.

```
       for (ArrayList<Bitmap> arr : imgs) {
            arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
            for (Bitmap img : arr) {
                if (img != null) {
                    arrayList.add(img.getHeight());
                }
                else {
                    arrayList.add(null);
                }
            }
            heights.add(arrayList);
       }
```

Comment: heights is the global Array<Array> and arrayList is the local Array. arrayList is updated, put into heights, and then cleared. Isn't it right?

Comment: @AndreaBR No, it's not. When you add `arrayList` to `heights`, you are not adding a copy of `arrayList`, you are just adding a reference to it. Therefore all the elements of `heights` refer to the same ArrayList.